# Stop ability to load site as both example.com and example.com/index.php

Tags: magento2.2.7

I've just noticed that I can load pages within and without `index.php` in the URL.

So, I can load these URLs:

- example.com
- example.com/index.php *(I don't want this)*
- example.com/product.html
- example.com/index.php/product.html *(I don't want this)*

I'm running M2+Apache, and would like to know how to stop this from happening.digital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the index.php's from your frontend URLs, by adding the following rewrite rules to your apache config (.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R,L]
```

**1st line:** turns on rewrite engine

**2nd line:** makes sure to leave index.php alone for all admin URLs

**3rd line:** removes index.php from the URL and redirects to that version ex. example.com/index.php/product.html becomes example.com/product.html

**4th line:** handles redirecting example.com/index.php to example.com/